# Do you improve edit or reject and edit when there are still many things that need to be fixed?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was going through the review queue and there was a suggest edit for  [Character constant too long for its type using switch case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262060/character-constant-too-long-for-its-type-using-switch-case).  The person who did the suggested edit just added code tags to the post when the post was in clear need of major editing.  When this happens should we use the improve edit to fix what is remaining or do you reject and edit to communicate to the editor that if they are going to edit a post they should fix as much as they can?

In this case I used the improve edit action and fixed what I could.  I had to go back and fix some more once I started writing this as I noticed I missed some things, so there are a couple revisions in the edit history.

Comment: By the way, your edit summary in IE or R&E is unrelated to the suggester's edit summary and will be listed separately; changing it to whatever is suitable for your edits is recommended, as you can't do anything about the suggester's summary anyway.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should be rejecting and editing.  The case you've described is exactly what that option is there for.

That said, the author of the post approved the edit before your review went through, so it wouldn't have had an effect on this suggested edit in either case.

Comment: @BalusC while I understand what you mean, maybe it is not just the rep size of the user that should be considered. It is to me more of a manner of understanding on how this site should be managed. I am sure a low-level OP with concise understanding will act in the right manner.

Comment: @BalusC: Because the post belongs to the OP, and they're allowed to reject edits to it, just like they can roll back changes after the fact.

Comment: @BalusC: This is not a *low rep reviewer*. This is a *low rep asker*, who is entitled to reject edits to their own post. They get no *points* for rejecting the edit. Read my last comment again: **the post belongs to the OP**. If they're rejecting an edit that would improve it in order to leave the question as is, that's fine. Vote on the question as it is - if it needed the edit to be a good question, and they rejected it, downvote or close vote the question. You're confusing *the poster of the question* and *reviewers*, and they're not the same.

Comment: Just an offtopic question, is there a way for users to have a look at edits which were improved (approve and edit) by reviewers?

Answer (score 22):

I generally only Improve Edits that are clearly on the right path, but simply didn't catch some unrelated bits that also need fixing: that is, the edit is itself *easily* good enough on its own to warrant being a permanent part of the post's revision history, but there are still issues I spotted while reviewing that I don't want to leave unaddressed. The threshold for Improve Edit is, if anything, a bit higher than for Approving, since it's a unilateral approval on my part.

I Reject and Edit whenever the editor should have done things differently: fixing trivial glitches while major flaws went unaddressed, or any of the usual rejection reasons, especially if my example can teach them better than an ill-fitting standard reason and more easily than typing a custom reason out. I also Reject and Edit if the edit is *staggeringly bad* and I don't want to risk it going through anyway; in such cases, a very fast R&E and grace period edit to actually fix it properly works wonders.

In this case, adding bogus tags while ignoring the rather substantial issues in the body clearly deserves a blunt rejection as soon as possible.

Answer (score 9):

That was an extremely minor correction (and the editor added tags for **both C and C++**!), while there were more issues to fix.

If the OP had not approved it, it ought to have been rejected.