# Reject and Edit – "Should have only improved formatting instead of correcting other things as well"

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

My [recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19475942) resulted in a *"reject and edit"* although one reviewer did accept it. So already there seems to be some disagreement on whether my edit was warranted. While I personally believe it was I would like to know what can objectively said to be wrong with my specific edit.

Changes I made:

- Improved formatting (applied code formatting, added one line break)
- Corrected multiple incomplete sentences, thereby slightly changing wording
- Correcting grammar (mainly capitalization)

Extent of the changes by the *reject & edit*:

- applied code formatting
- Corrected half of the capitalization errors on **I**, leaving several instances of **i** and other similiar errors

My **fictitious** quote in the title is the message I get here.

It is a common reason to reject and edit if [the edit is not thorough enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294409/do-you-improve-edit-or-reject-and-edit-when-there-are-still-many-things-that-nee). Clearly this is not the case, but what **did** I do wrong?

The only thing I can think of is construing my changes in wording as changes in intent, but I do not actually see that here.

Comment: Personally, I don't see any issue with your edit. I noticed though the reviewer was just into 2k rep, so probably they still need some guidance in reviewing properly.

Comment: It would arguably have been a little better to use code block formatting instead of inline code formatting for `export * from 'library/src/feature-path/feature-file'`, as you had put that into a separate line already. In any case, rejecting because of such a minor issue would have been extraordinarily pedantic.

Comment: The edit was fine and should have been accepted, the reviewer would have been better off using the "Improve Edit" option if they wanted to switch to code block formatting since they also missed other things that you had fixed when they used "Reject and Edit".

Comment: @ivarni That's what I was thinking. I suggested the relevant parts again and now the post is fine ;-)

Comment: Nitpicking, I feel like there might still be some awkward grammar in the question as it stands today (but I'm not 100% sure because I don't know Typescript), in my opinion, your original suggested edit was at least a big step in the right direction.

Comment: Spelling and grammar goes a long way to helping people understand a question. I don't see a problem with this. Worst case scenario is someone edits on top of your edit to improve it further. As long as we're moving forwards and not backwards; I don't see an issue here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Only one thing in your suggestion jumps out at me as doing *harm*: removing *"Scenario:"* at the beginning is kind of horrible. Besides being unnecessary, it's also grammatically wrong; using the simple present tense in that first sentence doesn't make sense without *"Scenario:"* in front of it.

(Some of the other changes don't improve the post as much as they could - for instance, it would've been better to make the `export ...` statement into a code block instead of just backticking it, and the phrase *"this way of imports"* is still awkward and ugly - something like *"this style of imports"* or *"this way of importing things"* would be better. But the fact that some of the improvements aren't *optimal* isn't a reason to reject.)

It would be defensible, but extremely harsh, for a reviewer to decide that breaking the grammar of the first sentence justifies a rejection, regardless of the merits of the other changes in the edit. That wouldn't be my choice, since on net I think the suggestion is definitely good; I'd've selected "Improve Edit", sorted out the first sentence, and made any further formatting tweaks I thought were warranted. Rejecting the edit *and* failing to apply some of the objectively good changes (like fixing the capitalisation of *"I"* in the prose) was sloppy on the reviewer's part, in my opinion - we shouldn't be throwing away clearly good changes that somebody has taken the time to write.